# Deleted Files from my IPhone still shows up when I hook my phone to Itunes

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

I deleted Music and Video from my Iphone 5, 8.1.2; But whenever I hook it up to the PC it still shows the deleted files as ghost datas under "On my device", furthermore Itunes says that my device has 6.05gb free space but my Iphone says 8.00gb free space. What is wrong with this? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution might be to factory reset your iPhone.
You can use this link for further guidance on this topic:
[Use iTunes to restore your iOS device to factory settings](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252).
:)